# Plot graph in Pandas or Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have tuple list as [(2014, 30, 15), (2015, 10, 20), (2007, 5, 3)]. 
  Now I want to plot bar graph in pandas in such a way that first index of each tuple on X axis and corresponding bars for second and third element on y axis. so for first tuple 2014 on x-axis and two bar for 30 and 15 respectively on y-axis. How can I achieve this using pandas plot function or in python matplotlib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sounds like you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [(2014, 30, 15), (2015, 10, 20), (2007, 5, 3)] )
df.columns = ['year','v1','v2']
df.set_index('year', inplace=True)
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

which gives:

[image]